# Is 'angle' used as a verb to mean 'to fish' acceptable in English?

Tags: verbs, bare-infinitive

> I can angle fish.

Is this sentence grammatically justifiable?

> I like angling

Is the verbal noun form grammatically correct?

Comment: Do not delete and repost closed questions. Fix them.